# How to use generics to infer my function second argument based on first argument's optional property?

Tags: typescript

I would like to get typescript to infer my second argument based on type of property "data" in my first argument. I've been struggling with this for a while now without success. Any tips on how to setup `type DialogHavingData`?

```
type DialogHavingData<T> = /* Do know how to deal with this here*/ 
    'data' in T ? T['data'] : any;

class MyDialog {
    data: { 
        prop1: string;
        prop2?: string;
        prop3: {
            name: string;
            age?: number;
        }
    };
}

class MyDialog2 {
    // data is optional
}

function createDialogFromClass<T = any, Y extends DialogHavingData<T>>(dClass: T, payload: Y) {
    // implementation here...
}

// MyDialog specifies "data" property so my second argument should have the same type
createDialogFromClass(MyDialog, {
    prop1: "my string",
    prop3: {
        name: "Test Name",
        age: 12
    }
    // should ask me to provide prop1 and prop2 which would be the type of 
})

// Any value is allowed because MyDialog2 doesn't specifiy the data property
createDialogFromClass(MyDialog2, null) 
createDialogFromClass(MyDialog2, {test: "My test dialog"});
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgQwDYHsDmAJBA3OA7NGBYBAHgBUA+KAXigHoAqWFKAazxQHcoALbqMFYATCMihc4wXoN5wAznwgAnCI3pQAsACgoeqAHJhxBAaj4o5KAH5LAbSMmDAXSgAuKAjwgA3Dp0AxkgI8ooAsiDwyOhQAN46+lDGJB6xWrqJ+mDKKGAAjB7ywMr4aH4ZmVDZuQBM1oXFpeWVetVgAMypCS2JeAgAthANJQTNPfoIaBD1UHgArv0ARipjlQC+3Xpr5RvagcGhUBFRqGg1cZsMGskI5oq5wHAofUg6uzoAZnN4AY-PUAFVMQICd0AAxHL9ADCB3kFFonm8ABooABNKAQAAewAgeGEilBmBwpSIJAolEoAAphDCQvIPOQUWAECBUAhhB5UQBKC4VK7mfpgJAQQZ4Eh-PBKVQAOllb382noGmOiFOUHkkACcA+cAgigARDd9VUcpBlKB1ax+iB1RAAs9hJ5lGgFrjgOr+HMkI7eDhoNJoPIBv7wBBAkCcYSIShobDKSromgUfE+W0ClB9db1Y0CPqkZc2p1eT0+oMPPryHr3QA5YN5y6JSZDKB5GqXXaJJUelBex0hNhQQaCVjVXCiE25PKIx1tc5cOQBGRcHveqDLWQhyBQFAfdJrLkKrsAQW8UGwyDm0AUniQqC4EEdywCCDm8mgCdO52EKD1eAM7o1O1tTgG0AySEwJzNUBwzESNVXBSFaVCeNIngs4UXmW8eRg4Eo0QuMP3QGpkxxIpywiQQqySND9X3cogA)

Answer (score 0):

Typescript doesn't have a way to know what is T and what properties does it have. To do it, you've to provide some kind of common behaviour.
You can do something like:

```
type DialogStructure = { [key: string]: string | number } 
type DialogWithData = { data?: DialogStructure }
```

This is going to support all types that follow that common structure, will allow objects with any key as string and values as string or numbers.
If data attribute is optional, you can use the ? helper to let typescript know this can be present or not.

The implementation should be something like:

```
createDialogFromClass<T>(classInstance: T extends DialogStructure): DialogWithData
```

So here you take a parameter with this dynamic object structure and return a DialogWithData instance.

Comment: This is invalid syntax. The constraint goes in the declaration, not where you use it (`<T extends DialogStructure>`, not `classInstance: T extends DialogStructure`).

Comment: Ty for the help guys. There a few things that differ from my needs. First I'm not passing and instance but the class itself and i'm not expecting the function to return `DialogWithData`. Actually, I'm expecting the second argument to be inferred.